# Why is the function assuming not taken in consideration?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, assumptions

In the following code, I assume that my variables are strictly positive. However, mathematica doesn't take this in consideration when it evaluates the If : the If is still in a non simplified form.

Why ?

```
In[99]:= Clear[PXMini, PXini, PM, lambda00, lambda00Bis, lambda, \
lambdaBis]

In[100]:= PXMini = Table[0, {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}];

In[101]:= PXMini[[1, 1]] = lambda00;

In[102]:= PXMini[[2, 1]] = lambda00Bis;

In[103]:= {PXMini[[3, 2]], PXMini[[5, 3]], PXMini[[7, 4]]} = {lambda, 
   lambda, lambda};

In[104]:= {PXMini[[4, 2]], PXMini[[6, 3]], 
   PXMini[[8, 4]]} = {lambdaBis, lambdaBis, lambdaBis};

In[105]:= PXini[x_] := Sum[PXMini[[x, k]], {k, 1, 8}];

In[106]:= PM[m_] := Sum[PXMini[[k, m]], {k, 1, 8}];

In[107]:= Infoi = 
 Assuming[lambda00 > 0 && lambda00Bis > 0 && lambda > 0 && 
   lambdaBis > 0, 
  Sum[If[PXMini[[x, m]] != 0, 
    PXMini[x, m]*Log[PXMini[x, m]/(PXini[x]*PM[m])], 0], {x, 1, 
    8}, {m, 1, 8}]]

Out[107]= 
3 If[lambda != 0, PXMini[x, m] Log[PXMini[x, m]/(PXini[x] PM[m])], 
   0] + If[lambda00 != 0, 
  PXMini[x, m] Log[PXMini[x, m]/(PXini[x] PM[m])], 0] + 
 If[lambda00Bis != 0, PXMini[x, m] Log[PXMini[x, m]/(PXini[x] PM[m])],
   0] + 3 If[lambdaBis != 0, 
   PXMini[x, m] Log[PXMini[x, m]/(PXini[x] PM[m])], 0]
```

Comment: It's easier to copy-paste if there aren't all those `In[]` labels. Consider `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ExportMultipleCellsOptions -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]`, if you want to make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, on such a small number of terms, `Sum` uses the `"Procedural"` method, which does not need any assumptions.  Second, `Piecewise[]` operates more like a function than `If[]`:

Incorrect result!:

```
Assuming[x == 0,
 Sum[If[x != 0, 1/n^2, 1/n^4], {n, 3}]
 ]
(*  3 If[x != 0, 1/n^2, 1/n^4]  *)
```

Correct result, but did not apply assumptions:

```
Assuming[x == 0,
 Sum[Piecewise[{{1/n^2, x != 0}}, 1/n^4], {n, 3}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `Simplify[]` inside `Assuming[]` to apply assumptions [*update notice*: I originally had `Simplify[]` outside sum, but since the summand depends on an external parameter, it probably makes more sense to apply `Simplify[]` to the summand directly]:

```
Assuming[x == 0,
 Sum[Simplify@Piecewise[{{1/n^2, x != 0}}, 1/n^4], {n, 3}]
 ]
(*  1393/1296  *)
```

The significant difference between [`If[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) and [`Piecewise[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) is that while both have the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), `Piecewise` does evaluate its arguments:

```
Block[{n = 2},
 If[x != 0, 1/n^2, 1/n^4]
 ]
(*  If[x != 0, 1/n^2, 1/n^4]  *)

Block[{n = 2},
 Piecewise[{{1/n^2, x != 0}}, 1/n^4]
 ]
(*  Piecewise[{{1/4, x != 0}}, 1/16]  *)
```

Another workaround:  Make the sum indefinite so that assumptions will be applied:

```
Assuming[x == 0 && k == 3,
 Sum[If[x != 0, 1/n^2, 1/n^4], {n, k}]
 ]
(*  1393/1296  *)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by If and Piecewise have the HoldAll attribute.I tried to find the exact definition on the documentation but it is written nowhere (at least for the If). Because for me saying that Piecewise has the holdAll attribute BUT evaluate its argument doesn't mean anything. (If he has a holdAll by definition it wouldn't evaluate its argument). However I can see that with your example the If doesn't evaluate the second & third arguments whereas the Piecewise does but I still don't understand what you precisely meant.

Comment: (I know the basic definition of HoldAll, for me what we put inside a HoldAll stays uncomputed, so HoldAll[1+1]=1+1 for example)

Comment: @StarBucK (1) You can find attributes with `Attributes[If]`, `Attributes[Piecewise]`, etc. You will see that `HoldAll` is among them. (2) `HoldAll` means that the arguments are passed to the function unevaluated, that is, in the form supplied in the function call. So the expression passed to `f` in `f[1 + 2]`, if `f` is `HoldAll`, would be `1 + 2` and not `3`. However, a function may evaluate its arguments or not.

Comment: Now, `If` evaluates its first argument. This can be seen by executing `Clear[x]; If[Print[x]; x == 0, 1, 2]`. It does not evaluate its 2nd or 3rd argument unless the first argument evaluates to `True` or `False`. `Piecewise` likewise will evaluate its arguments as can be seen in one of the my examples.

Comment: Ok thanks. However I am not sure to get why I would need to add a simplify in my code to make the thing work. I would like to really understand why it solves the problem because for me it is more like "oh it didn't finished the calculation ? So let's add a simplify to force it". Indeed as we had the assumption around, the If should know the condition of the If is true and return the second argument ?

Comment: @StarBucK You have to use a function that uses `$Assumptions` for `Assuming` to have any effect.  Since `Sum` does not in this case, you need something like `Simplify`. Since `Sum` sometimes applies `$Assumptions`, I can see that it's both confusing and irritating. Note that `If[]` does not look at `$Assumptions` at all.  Neither does `Solve` nor `Reduce`, which is perhaps more surprising.

Comment: Thank you it is more clear. Last question however :D. How do you know If doesn't look at assumptions, neither do sum in this case. It is just a trial and error ? Because it is written nowhere on the documentation. And, if I have an assumption that eats a simplify that eats a bunch of function, the simplification will be done on all the functions eaten by the simplify even if they don't use assumption (like the if in this example). I would like to understand the general scheme of what is happening.

Comment: For my last question, consider the following structure : Assumption[Simplify[f1[f2[f3...]]]. The simplification with the assumption will be done at all level inside the simplify (even if the functions do not use $assumption)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87605/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-starbuck).