# Replace an If by a combination using replacement rules

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Consider the following code :

```
tttest = a^2 + If[a > 0, a, -a]

a^2 + If[a > 0, a, -a]
```

I would like to replace my If function by something like fonction @ If. I did the following, but the replacement doesn't occur.

```
Replace[tttest, If -> (fonction @ If)]

a^2 + If[a > 0, a, -a]
```

How to make the replacement working and why isn't it working here ? For me it is an example of the same kind as the one in the documentation :

```
Replace[x^2, x^2 -> a + b]
```

---

[edit] : as suggested by the comment, I switched to ReplaceAll and I wrote the following : (the example is slightly different)

```
    ReplaceAll[If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0], 
 If[x1_, x2_, x3_] -> fonction [If[x1, x2, x3]]]

fonction[If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0]]
```

And here it works.

However, I want to actually simplify an expression linked to this question I asked [Why is the function assuming not taken in consideration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188476/why-is-the-function-assuming-not-taken-in-consideration/188479?noredirect=1#comment491502_188479)

I did the following :

```
 Assuming[lambda00 > 0 && lambda00Bis ,
```

ReplaceAll[If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0], 
  If[a1_, a2_, a3_] -> (gggg [If[a1, a2, a3]])]]

gggg[If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0]]

Here everything shows up correctly, but if actually my function gggg is Simplify, nothing is simplified (so the function "doesnt work" here).

```
Assuming[lambda00 > 0 && lambda00Bis , 
 ReplaceAll[If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0], 
  If[a1_, a2_, a3_] -> (Simplify [If[a1, a2, a3]])]]

If[lambda + lambdaBis != 0, PM[m] Log[PM[m]], 0]
```

Why ???

Comment: Use `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Or you can `Replace[tttest, If -> (fonction@If), Infinity, Heads -> True]`

Comment: @Alan I edited my message

Comment: About your edit: use `RuleDelayed`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match an expression with `Head` `If`. Therefore you need to use a pattern that will match that expression head. See the [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html) tutorial. You should also make use of [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) since you need to reference a named pattern from your replacement rule.

With

```
tttest = a^2 + If[a > 0, a, -a];
```

Then

```
tttest /. if_If :> fonction@if
```

> ```
> a^2+fonction[If[a>0,a,-a]]
> ```

Hope this helps.